# HTML form - respond to Enter key without focus

Tags: html, forms, jsp

My login jsp page uses a simple HTML form with input and submit fields.
when the focus (cursor) is on one of the input fields and I press Enter, the form is submitted as expected.  However, I would like the same behavior when there is no focus on one of the form's fields.

The scenraio is that when the page loads, the browser auto fills the input fields from its secret stash and I would like to press Enter and submit the form.

I searched this site but could find a relevant answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a little bit of JavaScript you can listen to the `keydown` event and then check for an enter key.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm... I have to press enter twice for the form to get submitted. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I added `id="form"` to the form element and put the script inside `<script type="text/javascript">` in the html head

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by implementing the `jQuery` `keypress` function. Like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(document).keypress(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```